# Positioning element within parent element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following script, which adds some buttons (fake buttons for now) to a div:

```
$("<div class='divButtons'>").appendTo( $(this).closest(".widget").find(".widget_header") );
// not real buttons, just text at the moment.  Trying to get the position right first.
$(".divButtons").text("(close), (min), (max), (help)").css({background:"red",float:"right"});
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the top-right corner of the `divButtons` to position itself to the top-right corner of the parent `.widget_header`.  I've tried adding `top:some_number_here`, but that doesn't work to well when moving the div with jQueries `ui-sortable`.

Comment: what if you use `css('right', 0)`?

Comment: @x4f4r, I've just tried this `.css({background:"red",float:"right",right:"0px",top:"0px"});` and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify style attributes via javascript, try adding something like this to your .css file:

```
.widget_header {
    position: relative;
}

.your-top-right-corner-class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This almost works, only problem is that the whole `.widget_header` disappears if I move the `.widget-header` using jquery-ui-sortable using IE8. I have to mouseout and mousein on the `.widget_header` for it to reappear again.  Removing the style sheet fixed the `.widget_header` disappearing act when moved.